# How to prevent the Mail app from restoring its previous state?

Tags: iphone, ios

The Mail app on my iPhone 5s crashes while launching. I assume that it is trying to restore its last state. Unfortunately that last state was what originally crashed it. So restoring that state results in a Mail app that will always crash on start up. What can I do to prevent the Mail app from restoring its last state on start up?

I already tried the following:

- disabling all Mail accounts
- send myself a mail to launch the Mail app from lock-screen
- closing the Mail app
- rebooting the phone
- contacted Apple support - only to find out that restoring an old backup is the only thing they know will help

I do not want to restore from a backup, because it is probably not possible to restore the Mail app backup only.

Comment: try holding down both the home button and the power button. This will do a full reboot. Then try opening Mail.app

Comment: @TheBro21 thanks for the comment but I missed to mention that I already already tried to reboot the phone without success.

Comment: Ok. That is the only thing I can think of. Another thing you. could try is do something in the Mail.app settings. Or sync, or restore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue without data loss. Here is what I did:

1. Created a backup from the iPhone while the Mail app was still broken
2. Run `Restore iPhone...` within iTunes (I tried `Restore Backup...` which did not fix the issue)
3. After the iPhone was reset to its factory defaults I set it up using the backup I did in 1.

Answer (score 0):

If I have just an app crashing I usually do a double-tap on the home button and swipe the misbehaving app **up** to "remove it from memory." This (I believe...) forces the iPhone to launch the app in it's default, rather than previous, state. And usually fixes app crashing issues.

Comment: Isn't this what "closing the ... app" means? The OP has also mentioned in comments that they've rebooted the phone, which should also have the same result; shouldn't it?

Comment: I am not sure if rebooting the phone will also remove the saved state or not, not something I have never checked. One would **think** that it would clear that but since it is such a quick thing to try I thought I would post it on the off chance it has the desired effect.